# Canon MP970 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 (Network Printing)

Tags: 12.04, networking, printing, canon

So I've got a Canon MP970 printer wich I would like to use with Ubuntu.

I've searched the internet but wasn't able to find any decent information on acquiring and installing the correct drivers etc. to use this printer as a network printer.

1) I Know my printer's IP adress (It has a fixed IP) 
2) On neither the Canon USA or Canon EU site are printer drivers for Linux.

Any help?

Kind Regards,

**S**

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is plug it into your machine, *even if you plan to use it as a network printer*. This should allow ubuntu to install the necessary drivers, and then you can use it on a network by ip.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repository for the Canon drivers. Just add this repository to your software sources by entering the command below in the terminal(Alt+f2).

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon

sudo apt-get update

Here is the list of all the available drivers [Canon Drivers List for Ubuntu](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/02/install-canon-printer-for-ubuntu-linux.html)

As for the networking issue go to System Settings >Printing >Add > Network Printer(Choose type). I usually choose Internet Printing Protocol(ipp) or you can Find Printer(enter IP address).

Comment: His printer model is not on the list

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [TurboPrint2](http://www.turboprint.info/) drivers for my Canon PIXMA MP 970 connected to the network.  The driver is only for the printer and not the scanner.  The drivers are not free, ~$37 USD for 3 printers with updates for 2 years. I have an older version (2.18-2) that I am able to use with 12.04 LTS 64-bit. The current version is TurboPrint 2.26-1 (21-Jun-2012).  The list of printers supported is [here](http://www.turboprint.info/printers.html).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install `libcups2-dev` from Software Centre.
2. Download, `make`, and `sudo make install` `cups-bjnp` (instructions [here](http://setdosa.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/setting-up-canon-pixma-mx850-on-ubuntu.html)).
3. Open Printers and network printers should be found.

This worked on 12.04 LTS, and connected to my MP970 straight away.